# Организовать очередь загрузки программ при запуске системы

Tags: windows, автозапуск

### Для начала

Не уверен вопрос в теме конкретно для StackOverflow из сети StackExchange. Если есть более подходящий сайт - перенаправьте пожалуйста.

### Описание

У меня установлен Google Drive для ПК и занимает оно виртуальный диск `G:`

[image]

С этим диском у меня связаны несколько операций. К примеру:

- Оно закреплено в панели быстрого доступа.
- Программа Media Player читает из него всю музыку и добавляет к себе в библиотеку.
- Программа Photos читает из него все фотографии и видео и так же добавляет в библиотеку.
  ...

Так как Google Drive при запуске системы запускается асинхронно, то все эти операции могут не выполнятся, поскольку в момент запуска других программ система не находит диск `G:`.

### Вопрос

Как можно организовать очередь загрузки программ при запуске системы?

Comment: Ну как вариант, написать cmd-файл, в котором прописать запуск Google Drive, цикл проверки появления диска G: и запуск остальных программ. Добавить этот cmd-файл в автозагрузку.

Comment: @LShadow77 а можно статьи по этой теме, или код? Я просто ни разу в этом не копался.

Comment: способ с cmd-файлом привёл в ответе. Подробнее про cmd - гуглите "windows cmd bat"

Comment: "У вашего метода та же проблема" - ну с добавлением в библиотеку в указанных программах проблем быть не должно. Что касается проблем с Explorer, то это оболочка винды - она загружается до запуска всех программ из автозагрузки, включая Google Drive. Решение с планировщиком заданий может помочь, т.к. в нём можно задать запуск программы при входе в систему, что, как правило, происходит до загрузки оболочки. Но гарантировать это нельзя, увы.

Comment: @LShadow77 то есть Google Drive "обречен" не быть закрепленным на панели быстрого доступа?

Comment: Этот виртуальный диск G создается каким приложением - гуглодиском или каким-то другим?

Comment: @Эникейщик да, гуглодиском.

Comment: А, я не так тогда понял. Тогда нужно запускать гуглодиск при старте без задержки.

Comment: @Эникейщик ну вот я и ставлю в начале Google Drive, потом Explorer. Запускаются они нормально, по очереди. Но этот диск G: появляется асинхронно и Explorer иногда успевает загрузиться до него. В таком случае диск G не закрепляется. Как я могу этот момент контролировать?

Comment: А попробуйте перезапустить проводник после того, как Google Drive загрузился. Если сработает, то можно добавить его перезапуск в скрипт автозагрузки. Подробнее, как это сделать, тут: https://remontka.pro/restart-explorer/

Comment: @LShadow77 сработало, спасибо.

Comment: @eccs0103 пожалуйста.